# Opening the redirected link

Tags: python, python-3.x

Note: New to Python.

I'm working on a bot, that whenever the prefix and command are given, it inserts a random wikipedia article. WikiPedia has a url for this.

'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random'

Instead of displaying the /wiki/Special:Random I want to display the random article it has redirected to and have it displayed at XYZ. How would I go about properly redirecting this?

```
elif message.content.startswith(config.prefix + 'edo'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, content = 'I like XYZ')
```

Comment: What library are you using to get response from `random` url?

Comment: I have imported urllib. Currently using response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random')